# How to style vue-datetime picker in laravel vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, datetimepicker

I am trying to use the vue-datetime component inside an other component here is the vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container p-3 bg-gray-100 flex flex-col">
    <div>{{ current_post.title }}</div>
    <div v-if="edit == false" id="mode-diplay">
      <div v-html="current_post.body" class="text-gray-700"></div>
    </div>
    <div v-else id="mode-edit">
      <form class="flex flex-col" action>
        <datetime type="datetime" v-model="datetime"></datetime>
        <input type="text" val="details.body" />

        <textarea
          class="markdown"
          name="editor"
          id="editor"
          v-model="raw_post.body"
          rows="50"
        ></textarea>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Datetime } from "vue-datetime";
export default {
  name: "PostDetails",
  props: ["current_post", "raw_post", "edit"],
  components: {
    datetime: Datetime,
  },
  data() {
        return {
            datetime:this.raw_post.beg_date
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

The vue-date time is displayed but when I click into the field input, the picker shows up vertically with very huge images of the < char.
I followed the example given here https://mariomka.github.io/vue-datetime/ and I don't know what else to do. The trouble is the same on Firefox and Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

> You need a specific loader for CSS files

Import in your parent component the style for the datepicker

```
import 'vue-datetime/dist/vue-datetime.css';
```

```
import { Datetime } from "vue-datetime";
import 'vue-datetime/dist/vue-datetime.css';
export default {
  name: "PostDetails",
  props: ["current_post", "raw_post", "edit"],
  components: {
    datetime: Datetime,
  },
  data() {
        return {
            datetime:this.raw_post.beg_date
        };
    },
};
```